# SUMs and Grouping By Date

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  t_stamp         views uviews hits uhits
1   7/18/2012 19:00 105   11     0    0
5   7/18/2012 20:00 1     1      0    0
2   7/19/2012 9:00  118   4      0    0
1   7/19/2012 10:00 196   18     0    0
7   7/19/2012 11:00 2     1      0    0
2   7/19/2012 12:00 38    11     0    0
2   7/19/2012 13:00 20    5      0    0
2   7/19/2012 19:00 9     2      0    0
2   7/20/2012 15:00 85    6      0    0
1   7/20/2012 16:00 483   101    2    2
2   7/20/2012 17:00 1200  240    0    0
2   7/20/2012 18:00 1200  232    0    0
2   7/20/2012 19:00 1199  231    0    0
2   7/20/2012 20:00 1200  236    0    0
2   7/20/2012 21:00 1201  237    0    0
1   7/20/2012 22:00 1220  187    0    0
1   7/20/2012 23:00 869   165    0    0
```

And my method is to combine them by the day so I can get a SUM for each of the last four columns.  The IDs do not really matter.

I am using this:

```
SELECT `bannerID` , DATE_FORMAT( `t_stamp` , '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS `date` ,
SUM( `views` ) AS `views` , SUM( `uviews` ) AS `uviews` , SUM( `hits` ) AS `hits` , SUM( `uhits` ) AS `uhits`
FROM test_bannerstats
WHERE DATE( t_stamp ) >= DATE( '2012-07-01' )
AND DATE( t_stamp ) <= DATE( '2012-08-24' )
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

However that doesn't seem correct to me as that the numbers seem conflicting.  In the end I want to get a daily tally the last four columns by day.

EDIT:

It is a problem with time zones it looks!  I will show you why...

Look at the table above, now let's do the additions for the entire day...

```
1   07/18/2012  106     12    0     0
1   07/19/2012  383     41    0     0
1   07/20/2012  8657    1635  2     2
```

Above is correct.  Below is wrong.

```
1   07/18/2012  105     11    0     0
1   07/19/2012  384     42    0     0
1   07/20/2012  4167    810   2     2
```

The problem?  Anything after 8pm is going to the next day.  It is a timezone issue that I have to sort out it seems.

Comment: What is the result given by the query you tried? By simply reading it, it would seem correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be simplified as:

```
SELECT `bannerID`,
        DATE_FORMAT( `t_stamp` , '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS `date`,
        SUM( `views` ) AS `views`,
        SUM( `uviews` ) AS `uviews`,
        SUM( `hits` ) AS `hits`,
        SUM( `uhits` ) AS `uhits`
FROM    test_bannerstats
WHERE   DATE( t_stamp ) BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-08-24'
GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)
ORDER BY DATE(t_stamp) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DATE(t_stamp), '%m/%d/%Y') AS `date`,
        SUM(views) totalViews,
        SUM(uviews) totalUViews,
        SUM(hits) totalHits,
        SUM(uhits) totalUHits,
FROM    tableName
WHERE   DATE( t_stamp ) >= DATE( '2012-07-01' ) AND 
            DATE( t_stamp ) <= DATE( '2012-08-24' )
GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to give your indexes a chance to be used, avoid using functions on columns when you can. Replace the conditions:

  ```
  WHERE DATE( t_stamp ) >= DATE( '2012-07-01' )
    AND DATE( t_stamp ) <= DATE( '2012-08-24' )`
  ```

  with:

  ```
  WHERE t_stamp >= DATE( '2012-07-01' )
    AND t_stamp < DATE( '2012-08-25' )
  ```
- You define the alias `date` in the `SELECT` list. This alias cannot be used in the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clauses (to be honest, it can be used at the GROUP BY clause but I wouldn't recommend it). Instead of:

  ```
  GROUP BY `date`
  ```

  use:

  ```
  GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)
  ```
- There is a proprietary MySQL syntax available (you can read it at the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) documenation) when the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are done on the same expression. Instead of:

  ```
  GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)
  ORDER BY DATE(t_stamp) ASC;
  ```

  you can use (for a slight efficiency gain):

  ```
  GROUP BY DATE( t_stamp ) ASC ;
  ```

The query becomes now:

```
SELECT 
    bannerID
  , DATE_FORMAT( DATE( t_stamp ), '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS `date` 
  , SUM( views ) AS views
  , SUM( uviews ) AS uviews
  , SUM( hits ) AS hits
  , SUM( uhits ) AS uhits
FROM 
    test_bannerstats
WHERE 
    t_stamp >= DATE( '2012-07-01' )
  AND 
    t_stamp < DATE( '2012-08-25' )     --- notice the `<` and the +1 date offset
GROUP BY
    DATE( t_stamp ) ASC ;
```

Comment: I think you mean `ORDER BY DATE(t_stamp) ASC` :D

Comment: @John: No, I meant what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're sql query wont really work, that is only applicable for date july 1 to august 24. What if the last 4 date is beyond that date? It wont pick up anything.

In my opinion the best way to do it is this:

```
  SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name order by id DESC limit 4;
```

Order by ID desc will sort the results in descending order. Limit 4, will only pick up the first 4 results.

Hope that helps.